# What does pressing CTRL do when editing a sprite sheet?

Tags: unity, spritesheet

I have a multi-sprite sprite sheet.  When I have a blue box selected, and I hold CTRL, the box turns green.  I have played with it, but cannot figure out what it does.  I checked the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html), but I don't see anything about turning the boxes green.

What does holding CTRL when editing a sprite within a multi-sprite sprite sheet do?

Comment: I think it snaps the sprites together if you move, them, although I'm not sure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd> in the Sprite Editor allows you to manually move the pivot point with snapping. With <kbd>ctrl</kbd> pressed (or<kbd>cmd</kbd> on a Mac), you can snap the pivot to one of the pre-defined locations, as defined under *Pivot* on the control panel: *Center*, *Top Left*, *Top*, *Top Right*, *Left*, *Right*, *Bottom Left*, *Bottom* and *Bottom Right*.

[image: Without holding own <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, the pivot moves freely around the sprite.]
[image: With <kbd>ctrl</kbd> held, the pivot snaps to the corners and sides.]

---

[The Unity manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html) does not mention this feature, though it does mention an alternate:

> ### Using the Editor
>
> **...**
>   [image: A picture of the Sprite Editor Control Panel, taken directly from the Unity Manual.]
>   ...
> There are also settings for the sprite’s pivot, which Unity uses as the coordinate origin and main “anchor point” of the graphic. You can choose from a number of default rectangle-relative positions (eg, Center, Top Right, etc) or use custom coordinates.
>   <sup>**- [Unity Manual: Sprite Editor](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpriteEditor.html)**</sup>

---

If I may speculate, I would say this feature has been implemented for the purpose of consistency. The manual does not deliberately mention it, but pressing <kbd>ctrl</kbd> to enable pivot snapping is a feature I have seen in other programs, before. While Unity officially directs you to use the control panel, the shortcut key has likely been implemented for users who are already use to holding <kbd>ctrl</kbd>. Such implementations are often referred to as *external consistency*, and helps facilitate human-computer interaction.